# MVC4 create membership tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a new MVC4 application.  It created the membership and userprofile tables on my sqlexpress db on my laptop.  I want to change this to create and use these on another server sql db.

How do I create these tables and tell my app to use these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So - and my DB is hosted on discountasp.net.  All you have to do is point a connection string called LocalSqlServer in web.config to the new db and then hit the default Account/Register page and the tables are created.